# Scoping a query based on a relation's calculated field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Let's say I've got the following (simplified) data model:

```
class Location
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :event_dates
end

class EventDate
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :event_sessions
  belongs_to :location

  def total_spots
    self.event_sessions.sum("max_participants")
  end

  def booked_spots
    self.event_sessions.sum("participants_count")
  end

  def available_spots
    self.total_spots - self.booked_spots
  end
end

class EventSession
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :event_date

  field :max_participants
  field :participants_count
end
```

I know can get a all of location's event dates simply:

```
Location.event_dates
```

But how can I scope the query to just get, for example, event dates with available spots? i.e.

```
Location.event_dates.where(available_spots > 0)
```

Since `available_spots` is a calculated value and not an actual database field of `EventDate`, that doesn't seem possible.  I was hoping to avoid adding those calculation methods to the DB itself, but if it's the only way....

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looks like the answer was hiding in plain sight (as usual), under the Extensions section of the Mongoid documentation:

[Relations - Common Behavior:  Extensions](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#common)

Two part answer:

First, the method I want is `select`, not `where`, so while I can't do what I proposed above, I *can* do:

```
Location.event_dates.select {|date| date.available_spots > 0}
```

To "scopify" that (in essense), what I want is to extend the relation as defined in Location as follows:

```
class Location
  has_many :event_dates do
    def with_available_spots
      @target.select {|date| date.available_spots > 0}
    end
```

So now I can call, simply:

```
Location.event_dates.with_available_spots
```

Et voila.

Comment: Doing a select here is forcing Rails to get all the event_dates, translate them as Ruby objects, and then inspect each one to see if they have available spots. I would look for a Data-base oriented solution to avoid this waste of resources.

Comment: Totally agree - thank you.  In fact, a friend who helped with this suggested the exact same thing.  Longer-term, it is better to have the database do the heavy lifting here rather than Rails.